# Facebook SDK fan page app issue

Tags: facebook, sdk, fan-page

In the last couple of days I've been building a new Facebook app that lets a user add a PHP CMS to their fan page that lets them build a full 'minisite' without any design or programming knowledge.

But, when I try to get the current page ID that the app is installed on, I don't get anything.

I'm using both HTTP and HTTPS, but I get nothing from either of them.

The code I'm trying to pull the data with is:

```
require "src/facebook.php";
$app_id = “MY APP ID”;
$app_secret = “MY APP SECRET”;
$facebook = new Facebook(array(‘appId’ => $app_id,
                               ‘secret’ => $app_secret,
                               ‘cookie’ => true));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

echo "<br>". $pageid;
echo "<br>". $page_admin;
echo "<br>". $like_status;
```

And im having these error messages:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant “247517918644221” - assumed '“247517918644221”' in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 6

Notice: Use of undefined constant “d7750be2ef0934bea4e2e8fe65a42a2a” - assumed '“d7750be2ef0934bea4e2e8fe65a42a2a”' in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 7

Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘appId’ - assumed '‘appId’' in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘secret’ - assumed '‘secret’' in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 10

Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘cookie’ - assumed '‘cookie’' in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: appId in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/src/base_facebook.php on line 213

Notice: Undefined index: secret in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/src/base_facebook.php on line 214

Notice: Undefined variable: pageid in /home/hazvuv/hazvuvp.com/why/index.php on line 22
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has unicode quotes and double quotes and PHP does not recognize them. See ‘ vs ' and ” vs ". It is hard to tell but they are different. Go through the code and replace the unicode quotes/double quotes with ascii quotes manually typed from you keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

replace quotations marks (“ ” ‘ ’) with regular quotes (' and ")